# Cuff word origin

Tags: etymology

I was wondering if the origin of the word (cuff/ to cuff) is Arabic as it exists in Arabic, pronounced exactly the same (kaf) and has the very same meaning (folding the end part of the sleeve or/and hitting somebody with palm exactly on the face)

I did quick look in the internet and found mostly "unknown origin" to the word. I would appreciate any hints about it as I'm interested in the etymology.

Comment: You are officially my favorite OP of the day for doing your research before asking. And my favorite source for etymologies, Etymonline, corroborates that research: it says of [*unknown origin, possibly from Swedish `kuffa` “to thrust, push”*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cuff#etymonline_v_439), which being of a similar theme, borrowing from a cognate in a foreign language, makes your own theory plausible, IMO. Though of course the Arabic might’ve borrowed the English, instead of vice versa.

Comment: I thought as well that it might be the other way around (English->Arabic) but still I need more evidences (for the time being can't afford researching time but I will do it very soon, it is just interesting to me)

Comment: Wait, this is on Meta? Weird. Hold on, we’ll migrate it to [main].

Comment: For the noun (the end of a sleeve) etymonline gives: "bottom of a sleeve," mid-14c., cuffe "hand covering, mitten, glove," perhaps from Medieval Latin cuffia, cuphia "head covering," which is of uncertain origin, perhaps ultimately from Greek.

Comment: 'cuff' in English is pronounced /kʌf/, which rhymes with 'tough'. The vowel is the same as in 'but' not the one in 'cot'. I make this explicit because you say that it is pronounced the same as 'kaf' and that is not the case, at least in General American English.

Comment: Can you give the Arabic (in Arabic characters) for the word? We should try in all directions.

Comment: I appreciate the responses :)
@Mitch interestingly enough you are saying probable Latin "cuffia" origin.... it is also the same used in old/formal Arabic for the head covering kind of hat or "Turban". ['cuff' is written in Arabic as 'كف' and if you accentuate the last letter with a small upward 3 used in Arabic like 'كفّ' it becomes to mean rolling/folding the sleeves]....excuse my late responses due to limited internet access for now

Comment: This is one of vanishingly small number of words that appear similar in Semitic and Indo-European *without* any evidence to support borrowing. The only one I know of is *can* meaning something tubular or a channel, and even here I'm not sure if much analysis has been done. Does anyone know of a list anywhere of this set that would obviously merit research as a group?

Comment: it occurred to me that the word should have root commonality with the word 'Coffin' which has as well in Greek unknown origin!... interestingly, in Arabic all these words have a common root, but the problem is, it is really hard to find any further details in/about Arabic etymology on the web as it is unfortunately poorly documented anywhere.

it may help if somebody can fetch first occurrence of the Greek word 'Kophinos' aka 'Coffin'. the date could tell in which language appeared first.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I believe whenever there is similarity there is a story! we are not talking about just phonetic coincidence here but accordance in different level of the word variation, which makes it more than a coincidence to me!

by the way 'can' or 'canal' also has a possible root origin to Semitic languages (i.e. Arabic/Hebrew) or back more ancient such as Assyrian origin. check the bottom of the page here https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cane

Comment: @wisdom When did "kaf" in the meanings given, enter Arabic?

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no necessary relationship between wearing a *cuff* and *cuffing* someone.

The Oxford English Dictionary says this about "cuff, n.1" (the clothing part):

> Middle English *coffe, cuffe*, of uncertain origin.
> The word has some similarity of form to Middle Latin *cuphia , cuffia* , in Old English *cuffie* , cap, head-covering, French *coiffe , coif* n.; but no connection of sense appears.

Aside from having a similar form, the etymology here is inconclusive. The earliest uses in English (from 14th and 15th centuries) refer to a *mitten or glove*, with the sleeve-meaning appearing in the early 16th century. Here is a helpful quote showing the earlier use:

> c1440   *Promptorium Parvulorum* 106   **Cuffe**, glove, or meteyne, *mitta* (J. *ciroteca*).

Attestations in the 16th century and afterward correspond to a fore-sleeve:

> 1522   in J. Raine *Testamenta Eboracensia* (1884) V. 154   My velvett jacket, to make his childer patlettes (i.e., neck garments) and **cuyffes**.
>
> 1594   T. Nashe *Vnfortunate Traveller* sig. C4   Cleane shirts and **cuffes**.

---

The hand-blow meaning is in "cuff, n.2" and "cuff, v.1," and the etymology appears just as uncertain and unrelated:

> Of uncertain origin: compare German Rogues' cant *kuffen* to thrash (‘perhaps of Hebraic origin’, Sievers); also Swedish *kuffa* to thrust, push.

This meaning is first attested in the early 16th century as well:

> 1530   J. Palsgrave *Lesclarcissement* 502/2   I **cuffe** one, I pomell hym about the heed, *Je torche*.

**Pummelling** (also in the quote as *pomell*) is derived from the name of an object that can be used in the action, a pommel, so it is certainly possible that **cuffing** is related to the name of an object that can be used in the action, a **cuff** (mitten or glove or sleeve; something covering the hand). There is just no firm example connecting the two, let alone a firm connection between the English *cuff*s and similar forms in other languages. So the similarity to Arabic could be a coincidence, or there could be an undiscovered connection via (for example) the use of German Rogues' cant.

---

Comment: Or it is plausible that Arabic borrowed 'cuff' from English/European uses, but that is probably not the case since [the etymology of كفّ ](https://www2.hf.uio.no/polyglotta/index.php?page=record&view=record&vid=626&mid=1219348) seems to be from proto-Semitic (related to the provenance of the Greek letter Kappa, borrowed from Phoenician).

Comment: But the connection between a blow with the hand and cloth near the wrist, though certainly not necessary or firm, is a very easy chain of metonymy (in either direction).

Comment: @Mitch Certainly the association is there. Given the different origins being cited, I can't rule out their being false cognates (cf. English *much* & Spanish *mucho*, which look similar but are etymologically unrelated) with some convergent evolution or folk etymology.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin The possibility of a false cognate in English, though, strengthens the idea that at least one of the meanings in Arabic (my money would be on the sartorial one since it seems to have appeared later) being borrowed from English.

Comment: Ok, I've been searching a bit in Arabic and I got to know so far that the term has appeared in poem as far as ~13 centuries ago. Secondly, the term originally means "protecting or gathering" as it is said that a city in Iraq was built and named as "Kufa" because 1- a big mountain was surrounding the city in sense of protecting it hence the name. 2- the man who decided to build the city on that spot said to his people come and gather yourselves here hence the name.
both meanings make sense for the use of the word as folding a piece of textile forming a hat to protect the head.

Comment: for that reason (it exists way before in Arabic context than English) it couldn't be borrowed from English in anyway. But still the possibility of being borrowed from other languages....I am looking for that and would love to know if so.